# laravel как сбросить сессию определенного пользователя?

Tags: laravel

в своем приложении меняю пароль опред. пользователям, но как сразу им сбросить сессию при смене пароля?

Answer (score 0):

<s>В таком случае после операций по смене пароля нжужно прописать либо [эту](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#deleting-data) строку кода:</s>

```php
$request->session()->flush();
```

Либо [эти](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298130):

```php
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
```

Это зависит от того, какую версию Laravel Вы используете.

UPD: понял, что эти строки кода удалят только самого человека, внесшего изменения, так что изменяю ответ.

Пусть у нас есть ID пользователя, сессию которого нужно завершить, тогда используем [метод `destroy($user_id)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#adding-custom-session-drivers) для принудительного завершения сессии именно этого пользователя.

Comment: но получается он применит эти команды мне же, тесть текущему пользователю ?

Comment: @Олег виноват, ответ вышел неточный, изменил

Comment: `public function destroy($sessionId)`  - нужно знать id сессии, а не пользователя. И снова, у пользователя может быть несколько сессий. Нужно найти все сессии пользователя и закрыть их. Но как? Зависит от того, где хранятся сессии. Если в БД [как тут](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites), то так: `Sessions::where('user_id', $user_id)->delete()`. Для других драйверов - другая реализация.

Comment: уже сделал по одному примеру, сесию в базу, а потому уже удаляю где надо